# Can't find SQL 2005 client and repoting tools after install

Tags: sql, service, reporting

I've gone through the related questions and I'm still stuck.

I installed SQL 2008 R2 Express and then it turned out I needed reporting services client tools in SQL 2005.

I uninstalled SQL 2008 and installed SQL 2005 with all options set.

However, I can't find ANY client tools (studio, reports, etc.) in the SQL 2005 folder.

Any clue as to what's going on?? No errors were reported during installation and SQL 2005 SP4 is installed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you installed, whether it was 2005 or 2008 and whether it was express or not.

Comment: Yes, 2005 Standard and 2008 Express before that. After uninstalling everything yesterday I re-installed 2005 and now everything works =)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143718%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).  It sounds like you installed only the database portion, and not the other components.

Comment: Thanks @Holocryptic. However, I definitely installed the client components, twice. I think there might have been an issue with installing 2005 and 2008 Express together. What I did was clean and purge anything mentioning SQL and re-installed 2005, now no problems! Thanks!